# Hapi.js - adding mechanism to check every route

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to implement a mechanism that will be run before any route is hit. In that mechanism I want to take a value from the header and check for authentication.

I have come up with this:
server.js:

```
// Create a server with a host and port
'use strict';

var Hapi = require('hapi');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var plugins = [      
  require('./routes/entities')
];
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
   port: 3000
});
//Connect to db
server.app.db = mongojs('hapi-rest-mongo', ['entities']);

server.app.checkHeader = function (request) {
var header = request.headers['x-authorization'];
if(header === "letmein"){
    return true
}
return false
};
  //Load plugins and start server
server.register(plugins, function (err) {

if (err) {
    throw err;
}

// Start the server
server.start(function (err) {
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
   });
 });
```

and in routes.entities:

```
'use strict';

var Boom = require('boom');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var Joi = require('joi');

exports.register = function (server, options, next) {

var db = server.app.db;

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/entities',
    handler: function handler(request, reply) {

        if(!server.app.checkHeader(request))
        {
            return reply(Boom.unauthorized());

        };

         //request.server.myFunc();
        db.entities.find(function (err, docs) {

            if (err) {
                return reply(Boom.wrap(err, 'Internal MongoDB error'));
            }

            reply(docs);
        });
    }
});
```

So in short while starting the server I have registered my function **server.app.checkHeader**

And in the routes I am calling it and sending a **request** object to it. Request object contains information about the headers.

While this works, I am having a feeling I am not following the best practices with the Hapi.

How could I do it more elegantly?

Comment: A hook? onPreHandler for example. See http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle. I guess that it is better to use Hapi's own auth facilities in this case.

Comment: Inplementing a strategy, an example https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie/blob/master/lib/index.js

Comment: I have it already implemented. This one I need only for headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to require authentication for all or selected route is to use hapi’s integrated functionality.

You should [set a default authentication strategy](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-set-a-default-authentication-strategy) that is applied to each route handler. The sample below uses basic auth. You’d want to create a custom authentication strategy for hapi to check your `x-authentication` header.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi')  
const BasicAuth = require('hapi-auth-basic')
const server = new Hapi.Server()

server.register(BasicAuth, function (err) {  
  if (err) {
    console.log('error', 'failed to install plugins')
    throw err
  }

  // TODO: add authentication strategy & set as default
  server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', true, { validateFunc: basicValidationFn })  

  // or set strategy separately as default auth strategy
  server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validateFunc: basicValidationFn })  
  server.auth.default('simple')  


  // TODO: add routes

  server.start(function (err) {
  })
})
```

You can also inject [hapi’s request lifecycle and extend it](https://futurestud.io/downloads/hapi/request-lifecycle) at given points. Extending the request lifecycle should be done by [using plugins](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-create-your-own-custom-plugin):

```
register: function (server, options, next) {
  // do some processing before 'onPreAuth'
  // or pick another extension point
  server.ext('onPreAuth', (request, reply) => {
    // your functionality
  })
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options.

You can, of course, tap into the [request lifecycle](http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle) - note the events that occur in the pipeline prior to the route handler.

Although, I'd urge you to consider implementing an auth strategy that can be set as the default for all routes or selectively on appropriate routes.